# Im not able to figure out how do I add required attribute to the Menu Component provided by Headless.ui

Tags: reactjs, validation, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I have a form in which I have rendered a seperate Dropdown component in which I imported a dropdown from Headless Ui . So When I press the submit button of the form , I want the dropdown component to have some value before submit just like when a select element with required attribute works. But I'm unable to figure out whats the prop which will make the Menu component work like that without me manually writing the logic.

```
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { BiChevronDown } from 'react-icons/bi'
import {LuAsterisk} from 'react-icons/lu'

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function DropDown({label}) {

    const [optionValue, setOptionValue] = useState("Select an option");

    const handleSelect = (e) =>{
        const selectedOption = e.target.value;
        setOptionValue(selectedOption);
      };

  return (
    <Menu as="div" className="w-[49%]  relative inline-block text-left">
         <div className='flex gap-[2px] items-center'>
          <label>{label}</label> <LuAsterisk color='red'/>
          </div>
      <div className='flex h-[40px] mt-1'>
        <Menu.Button className="flex justify-between items-center w-full  gap-x-1.5 rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-[#E0E0E0] hover:bg-gray-50">
          <span className='text-sm font-normal text-[#637381]'>{optionValue}</span>
          <BiChevronDown className="-mr-1 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
        </Menu.Button>
        
      </div>

      <Transition
        as={Fragment}
        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
      >
        <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-full origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
          <div className="py-1">
            <Menu.Item>
                
              {({ active }) => (
                <option className={classNames(
                    active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                    'block px-4 py-2 text-sm'
                  )}
                  onClick={handleSelect}>Srinagar</option>
              )}
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                
              {({ active }) => (
                <option className={classNames(
                    active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                    'block px-4 py-2 text-sm'
                  )}
                  onClick={handleSelect}>Jammu</option>
              )}
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                
                {({ active }) => (
                  <option className={classNames(
                      active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                      'block px-4 py-2 text-sm'
                    )}
                    onClick={handleSelect}>Account Settings</option>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                
                {({ active }) => (
                  <option className={classNames(
                      active ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-700',
                      'block px-4 py-2 text-sm'
                    )}
                    onClick={handleSelect}>Canada</option>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
          </div>
        </Menu.Items>
      </Transition>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

I tried using a select element with required attribute but that didn't seem to work.